# Security mp_init and init memory leaks

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks

I build an iPad application and profile it with XCode, I got memory leaks in Security framework, following is some of them from Instruments:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 128 Bytes,4  < multiple >    512 Bytes   Security    mp_init
 Malloc 128 Bytes,  0x824aa70   128 Bytes   Security    mp_init
 Malloc 128 Bytes,  0x824a9f0   128 Bytes   Security    mp_init
 Malloc 128 Bytes,  0x824a970   128 Bytes   Security    mp_init
 Malloc 128 Bytes,  0x824a8f0   128 Bytes   Security    mp_init

Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 16 Bytes,4   < multiple >    64 Bytes    Security    init
 Malloc 16 Bytes,   0x824a550   16 Bytes    Security    init
 Malloc 16 Bytes,   0x824a540   16 Bytes    Security    init
 Malloc 16 Bytes,   0x82493d0   16 Bytes    Security    init
 Malloc 16 Bytes,   0x8237ca0   16 Bytes    Security    init
```

and some of the details:

```
#   Category    Event Type  Timestamp   RefCt   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc 128 Bytes    Malloc  00:02.240.888   1   0x824aa70   128 Security    mp_init

#   Category    Event Type  Timestamp   RefCt   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc 16 Bytes Malloc  00:02.240.886   1   0x824a550   16  Security    init
```

I use ASIHTTP, FMDatabase and some other frameworks(I do not think they will cause the problem) in my application, and no Security framework in "Link Binary With Libraries", so I have no idea what's going wrong.

Can anyone figure out what may cause the leaks?

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or on a device - if it's the simulator, run the tests on a real iPad. The simulator has a different memory model and reports false positives (and possibly suppresses valid leaks as well!)